# Strategy not being called by authenticate

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm new to node and am trying to get a simple local login up and running using passport.js. It looks to me that the strategy that I have set up is not being run when the authenticate function is called.

```
       module.exports = function(app) {
var mongo = require('./mongoose-db.js');
var brands = require('./app/brands.js');

// brand admin page //

var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy( {//this is a strategy but why is it not being run?
    usernameField: 'admin_username',
    passwordField: 'admin_password'
  }, 
  function(username, password, done) {console.log('here 7');
    process.nextTick(function () {
      console.log('here 8');
      // Find the user by username.  If there is no user with the given
      // username, or the password is not correct, set the user to `false` to
      // indicate failure and set a flash message.  Otherwise, return the
      // authenticated `user`.
      mongo.findAdminByUsername(username, function(err, user) { console.log('here 9');
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown Admin ' + username }); }
        if (user.password != password) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' }); }
        return done(null, user);
      })
    });
  }
));


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

app.get('/brand_admin', function(req, res){
    console.log('here 1');
  res.render('admin_login', { user: req.user, message: req.session.messages });
});


app.post('/brand_admin', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('USER: ');
    console.log(req.user);
    res.send('ok');
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        console.log(user);
    if (err) { return next(err) }
    if (!user) {console.log(req.session.messages);
      req.session.messages =  [info.message];
    console.log('here 4');
    console.log(req.session.messages);
      return res.redirect('/brand_admin')
    }
    console.log('here 5');
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); console.log('here 6');}
      return res.redirect('/');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

the ejs is:

```
<body>

<head> Admin Login </head>

<form id="brand_edit" action="/brand_admin" method="post" >
        <fieldset>

        Login: <input type="text" name="admin_login" > <br>

        Password: <input type="password" name="admin_password" >

        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Login"/>

        </fieldset>

<a href="">Forgotten your password?</a>

</form>

</body>
```

The output i'm getting from form submission is:

```
Steve
agrgegerfe
{ id: 1,
  username: 'Steve',
  password: 'agrgegerfe',
  email: 'bob@example.com' }
false
undefined
here 4
[ 'Missing credentials' ]
here 1
```

The strategy is not running but I can't figure out why? Can anyone help? One thing that could be affecting this is that I am using passport for Facebook login in another section of the application..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are not calling passport properly. It needs to be in the route chain. Try this:

```
// configure passport with the correct fields
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'admin_login',
  passwordField: 'admin_password'
}, function (username, password, done) {
  ...
});


app.post('/brand_admin', passport.authenticate('local'), function (req, res) {
 // req.user is now defined
 console.log(req.user);
 res.send('ok');
});
```

Comment: Hi Laurent, thanks for your response. I tried adding in the the appropriate definitions of usernameField and passwordField but the user is still undefined. I think this is what is causing the problem as the authenticate function is returning as failed from the get go. I can't see where I have gone wrong tho..

Comment: can you post your full code somewhere ? I'm suspecting a problem in the client side.

Comment: Sure. Have posted above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The username field is called "admin_login" in the form, but "admin_username" in your strategy.